# How to check if a bash shell attribute has been set up?

Tags: bash

`set -o posix` will set the POSIX attribute of the bash shell.

How can we check if an attribute has been set up or not?

Comment: @JeffSchaller `extglob` belongs to the `shopt` list of options, but the `set` list of options is not explained in that answer. (`shopt posix` will fail).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two lists of options in bash. One for `shopt` and one for `set`.

#### Check one option.

To print an specific option (without changing it) for shopt, use `shopt -p name`:

```
$ shopt -p xpg_echo
shopt -u xpg_echo
```

And for `set`, use: `shopt -po name` (yes, you may use `shopt -op` for `set` list).

```
$  shopt -po xtrace
set +o xtrace
```

#### List options.

To list all options from shopt, use `shopt` (or reusable `shopt -p`).
Also `shopt -s` or `shopt -u` could be used.

The way to list all options to `set` is with `set -o` (related: `set +o`).
Or: `shopt -o` is equivalent to `set -o` and `shopt -op` is to `set +o`.

#### Manual

From `LESS=+/'^ *shopt \[' man bash`:

> With no options, or with the -p option, a list of all settable options is displayed,
>   If  either  -s  or  -u  is  used  with no optname arguments, the display is limited to those options which are set or unset, respectively.

From `LESS=+/'^ *set \[' man bash`:

> If -o is supplied with no option-name, the values of the current options are printed. If +o is supplied with no option-name, a series of set commands  to  recreate the current option settings is displayed on the standard output.

#### Examples

```
$ set -o
allexport       off
braceexpand     on
emacs           on
errexit         off
errtrace        off
functrace       off
hashall         on
histexpand      on
history         on
ignoreeof       off
interactive-comments    on
keyword         off
monitor         on
noclobber       off
noexec          off
noglob          off
nolog           off
notify          off
nounset         off
onecmd          off
physical        off
pipefail        off
posix           off
privileged      off
verbose         off
vi              off
xtrace          off
```

And

```
$  shopt -sp
shopt -s checkwinsize
shopt -s cmdhist
shopt -s expand_aliases
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s extquote
shopt -s force_fignore
shopt -s histappend
shopt -s histverify
shopt -s interactive_comments
shopt -s progcomp
shopt -s promptvars
shopt -s sourcepath
```

It is worth mentioning about `shopt -op` which actually lists `set` options:

```
$ shopt -op
set +o allexport
set -o braceexpand
set -o emacs
set +o errexit
set +o errtrace
set +o functrace
set -o hashall
set -o histexpand
set -o history
set +o ignoreeof
set -o interactive-comments
set +o keyword
set -o monitor
set +o noclobber
set +o noexec
set +o noglob
set +o nolog
set +o notify
set +o nounset
set +o onecmd
set +o physical
set +o pipefail
set +o posix
set +o privileged
set +o verbose
set +o vi
set +o xtrace
```

Comment: Thanks. What do the env var `LESS`ant its value `+/'^ *set \['`  in  `LESS=+/'^ *set \[' man bash` mean?

Comment: @Tim Just copy the whole line to your shell and execute it.

Answer (score 4):

Use something like

```
if shopt -qo posix ; then
```

To unset the option, use

```
set +o posix
```

See `man bash`, `help set`, and `help shopt` for more details.

Comment: Thanks. How can I unset it? Is it correct that the command `unset` is to unset a variable or function, not a shell attribute?

Comment: @Tim: updated, simplified.

Comment: Thanks. `help set` says `set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]`. Does it mean that the option `-o` must be followed by an option argument `option-name`?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I missed the `+` part. But still doesn't `help set` implies `-o` must be followed by an option argument `option-name`?

Comment: @Tim: My version says much more.

Comment: @Tim: `set -o` without the option name show all the options.

Comment: I learned it from your reply. But does `help set` mention that?

Comment: @Tim: `man bash` mentions it.