# What does If ! shopt –oq posix; exactly mean?

Tags: shell-script, posix

```
If ! shopt –oq posix; then
```

I've searched all the pages about this, but I haven't found a clear explanation for it. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Converse of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269794/70524 (indeed, *this* appears it in [the very next answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269776/70524)

Comment: This command id not related to `POSIX`, it is rather a non-portable `bashism`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `If` is actually `if`, the line introduces an `if` statement that runs the command `! shopt -oq posix` as a test.

The `shopt` utility in the `bash` shell is a utility used for setting certain shell options.  This utility can also be used to test whether a particular shell option is set or not.  This is what the utility is used for in the `if` statement in the question.

The `-o` option makes it expect that the option given is one of the options that are valid for `set -o` (see `help set` in `bash`), and the `-q` option makes the utility quiet, i.e. it will only produce an exit status but no output.  The exit status of `shopt` will be used by the `if` statement to determine whether to execute the body of the `if` statement or not.

The test checks whether the `posix` shell option is set in the `bash` shell, and if it isn't (the interpretation of the result of the `shopt` call is inverted by the preceding `!`), the body of the `if` statement would be executed.

See also `help shopt` in an interactive `bash` session.

The `shopt` utilitiy is not a standard utility, but a built-in utility provided by the `bash` shell specifically.

Comment: Please keep in mind that a `bash` with `set -o posix` active is still not `POSIX/UNIX` compliant. You need at least to set `shopt -s xpg_echo` in addition.